# Using PyDev when source code is not organized as a Python Project

Tags: pydev

I've been using Eclipse with PyDev for a while and I find PyDev to be a really great tool. Although there is one big obstacle which I can't figure out how to solve. The problem is as follows:

The source code I am working with is version controlled by Git. The repository structure is not anything like the structure of a typical Python project. I can not change the structure of the repository, it is like it is due to historical reasons and due to the fact that not only Python code is stored in the repository; C/C++, JavaScript, SQL etc source code is in the repository alongside with the Python code. Also, most other developers working with the source code does not use Eclipse or any other IDE, so there is no momentum for changing the current layout.

Trying to cope with the situation I have created a script which produces a Python directory structure consisting of (hard) links to the original source files. This is not a good solution, e.g. each time I switch branch I need to re-generate the links. Also Git features, such as annotate etc does not work when used on the linked files. There are a lot of other drawbacks as well.

Here's two examples showing the (lack of) structure in the repository in question:

repository:/components/foopackage/foopackage/barpackage/ gets deployed as:
namespace-package.foopackage.barpackage

Another example:

repository:/components/foopackage/core/core/ gets deployed as:
namespace-package.foopackage

The actual package-names (or rather directory/map names) in the repository does not neccesary indicate how the python-package should be named, that information is located in separate build-system meta-files. The script I mentioned above derives the above transformations from those meta-files.

What I think I need is some way to define a logical-view transformation on the repository layout.

I am interested in any suggestion regarding how to solve this issue? It would be really nice to understand what my options are.

Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem for PyDev... there are some alternatives for solving this:

1. Get the code and create a new project using the same location you've downloaded the code (and if other devs don't mind, commit the .project and .pydevproject files -- next time it'll be a matter of doing file > import > existing projects into workspace). See: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIimportexistingprojects%2FsourcesintoPyDev%3F for details.
2. Just create a new project in the PyDev workspace in any place and in the first wizard page when configuring PyDev you can select 'create links to existing sources (select them on the next page)'. And then reference the existing sources there.

I think option 1 is better as it's easier when checking the code out a 2nd time -- for option 2 you have to repeat the steps anytime you clone the project again in a different location.

### UPDATE1:

Given the changes which added more info, I agree... it's a really weird setup :)

(i.e.: Probably you have a lot of scaffolding just for running/testing the code locally with those changes in the actual namespace vs disk-layout)

Well, with this use-case I think that having a script which creates a structure with symlinks is the only viable choice (so that you can actually mimic the actual namespace that you'd have when running Python), although I think the best approach would be at least having the structure beneath the PYTHONPATH folders in disk the same you'd have when running Python (if that was the case, just setting the source folders in approach 1 or 2 would work) -- if you can convince your team that this is the only sane approach for a Python project layout :)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Although I don't think the suggested solution is valid for this specific scenario. The question was unclear. I have edited the original post and added two examples to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Note: if you go for the symlinks you should probably have 2 things: a pydev-project with the symlinks and a secondary project which has the whole git structure 'as is' so that you can use egit on it without any issues.

Comment: Yes, using a separate PyDev-project for the symlinks and one project for the git structure is how I currently cope with the situation. I think it will be hard to change the disk-layout.